# Issue loading the caret function in R

Tags: r, caret

I'm trying to find the RMSE for a train & test subset of the data for my grad class and I'm running into some big problems trying to open the caret function after installing the package of the same name.

The error message that I'm getting is

```
Error in readRDS(mapfile) : unknown input format
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘caret’:
unable to load R code in package ‘stringi’
```

I have R version 4.3.1 and I'm on a MacBook air with a 1.8 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5

I have tried restarting the session. I have tried removing packages. I saw online that some people recommend 'hard deleting' packages before re-installing but I'm not sure what they mean by that, I'm not very R advanced. I have tried rebooting my machine. I've tried some other code (from an online source) that recommended looking for 'bad files' but I didn't have any luck with that either. I've tried running other install code for dependencies.

I'd appreciate a response as soon as possible.
Thanks guys!

Comment: To 'hard delete' a package, run `.libPaths()` at an R prompt, those are the directories where your installed packages are. Search for the directory with the package name and delete the directory.

Comment: What happens when you `install.packages("caret")` (reinstall), regardless of hard-delete?